# Function to check whether a binary tree is binary search tree or not?

Tags: recursion, boolean, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I attempted writing the following method which tells whether a Binary Tree is Binary Search Tree or not? I pass only half of the test cases. What am I doing wrong?

```
boolean checkBST(Node root) {

    boolean leftflag = false;
    boolean rightflag = false;

    Node l = root.left;
    Node r = root.right;

    if(l!=null) { 
        if(root.data <= l.data) {
            leftflag = false;
        }
        else { 
            leftflag = true;
            checkBST(l);
        }
    }
    if(leftflag == false)
        return false;
    if(r != null) {
       if(root.data >= r.data) {
           rightflag = false;
       }
       else {
           rightflag = true; 
           checkBST(r);
       }
    }
    if(rightflag == false)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  Specifically, your posted code does nothing: there's no test driver.  Also, you fail to demonstrate a failing case.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a case where your program could return wrongly false.

Imagine you have a tree with 3 branches deep going as follow :

```
           7
        /     \
       3       8
        \     / \
         4   6   9
```

Your program starts up at 7 (root), creates two boolean at false (leftflag and rightflag), checks if left is null. It isn't. It then checks if the data of left <= the data of right. It is.

So you recursively call your function with a new root node left (3 in the example). Again, it creates your two boolean at false initial value, checks if left node is null. It is ! So it skips the whole if, goes directly to your other if before the return.

```
// The condition here is respected, there is no left node
// But the tree is an actual search tree, you didn't check right node
// Before returning false.
if(leftflag == false)
   return false
```

What i'd do is

```
if(l != null)
{
   if(root.data<=l.data)
   {
       return false;
   }
   else
   {
      // recursive call here
   }
}

if(r != null) 
{ 
   // Same as left node here 
}
```

so even if your left node is null, the program still checks for the right node. Hope i helped out a little bit !

Answer (score 0):

Your primary mistake is that you ignore the return value of your recursive calls.  For instance:

```
    else { 
        leftflag = true;
        checkBST(l);
    }
}
if(leftflag == false)
    return false;
```

If checkBST(l) returns false, you ignore it.  You never save the value.  Thus, your subsequent check for leftflag is utterly ignorant of the subtree's suitability.  Semantically, your routine assumes that all subtrees are BSTs -- you set the flag, recur on the subtree, but don't change the flag.  Try this logic:

```
else
    leftflag = checkBST(l)
```

Now, please get comfortable with Boolean expressions.  For instance, testing a Boolean value against a Boolean constant is a little wasteful.  Instead of

```
if (flag == false)
```

Just check directly:

```
if (!flag)
```

Checking a pointer for null is similar in most languages:

```
if (l)
```

Finally, don't initialize your flags if you're simply going to set them to the same value as the first action.

Now, your code might appear like this:

```
    boolean leftflag = false;
    boolean rightflag = false;

    if(l) { 
        if(root.data > l.data) {
            leftflag = checkBST(l);
        }
    }
    if(!leftflag)
        return false;

    if(r) {
       if(root.data < r.data) {
           rightflag = checkBST(r);
       }
    }
    if(rightflag == false)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Now it's a little easier to follow the logic flow.  Note that you have a basic failure in your base case: a null tree *is* balanced, but you return **false**.

Now, if you care to learn more about logic short-circuiting and boolean expressions, you can reduce your routine to something more like this:

```
return
    (!root.left ||            // Is  left subtree a BST?
      (root.data > root.left.data &&
       checkBST(root.left)))
    &&
    (!root.right ||           // Is right subtree a BST?
      (root.data > root.right.data &&
       checkBST(root.right)))
```